# Error with routes

Tags: model-view-controller, scala, playframework, routes, akka

I'm new to play, scala, and akka and I am getting an error when using sbt to build it and compiling it by loading localhost in a web browser. The in browser error I'm getting is:

Compilation error
reference to routes is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by import controllers._ and import models._

```
In /Users/Louis/Documents/play_actors/app/views/form.scala.html at line 9.
5@main(Html("Calculate Pi")) {
6    
7    <h2>Calculate Pi</h2>
8    
9    @helper.form(action = routes.Pi.submit) { 
10        
11        <fieldset>
12            <legend>Pi Options</legend>
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I call the html file from Activity.scala:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

import views._

object Application extends Controller {

    def index = Action {
        Ok(html.form(Pi.optionsForm))
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play generates a number of Scala files including ones based on your `routes` file and your templates.  If you look in the `target/scala.2.9.1/src_managed` directory after you've attempted to compile your app, you should find a `views.html` package containing Scala versions of your templates and a controllers package containing a Scala representation of your `routes`.

As well as a number of Play's own packages, Play templates will automatically import everything in your controllers and model packages.  This includes the routes class generated from your routes file, which allows you to reference them in the way you've shown.

I assume that you must have some object or class in your model package which shares the name routes and hence, creates a collision which the compiler can't resolve.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!1 I was able to fix it by moving all the models into my controllers package, navigating to my models folder that Play generated and deleted that folder.

Thank you for your in depth explanation and sharing your knowledge. +1.